# Azure Function App project/repo structure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm fairly new to Function Apps, anyways we have about a dozen small programs currently running as Windows scheduled tasks on an Azure VM and we are looking to migrate these to PaaS.  Most of these are small console type background processes that might make an API call, perform a calc, and store the result in a db, or maybe read some data from a db and then send out an email.  We have a mixture of pwsh, Python, and .NET.

Anyways I was wondering how many repos I should have?  I assume I would need at least 3 (one for each runtime stack).  Also I didn't want to create a separate repo per app and end up having 50 git repos eventually.  I don't know if it's best just to make some root level folders using the app names in the repo to keep the structure separate looking?

Lastly should each of these apps be hosted in their own function app (Azure Resource), or can I have several of the apps hosted in a single FA?  I'm not sure if splitting everything up into separate function apps would make deployment easier or not.  I guess ease of long term support/maintenance would be the most important aspect to me.

Short version: What is considered the best practice for logically grouping and creating the relationship/mapping between your apps, number of git repos, and azure function app resources?

Comment: Have you gone through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob

Comment: you could have each functional domain as a function app and all related functionality as functions in the function app. You could also standardise on a single language such as C#